# How to write a variable to an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a question. How do you write a variable to an XML file using Linq to XML? I have it set up so that the variable gets put in a public variable

```
     public string name;
     public string age;
```

The value that is put into these is

```
     this.name = characterTextBox.Text;
     this.age = characterageTextBox.Text;
```

Now I have created a class that handles the placement of these variables into the XML file, but everytime I attempt to retrieve the variable from the public string, It always comes out as null; even though I tested to see if it was null when I saved it to the public variable.
Here is the saving code

```
    Form1 f = new Form1();
        String name = f.name;
        String age = f.age;


        var doc = XDocument.Load(XMLFILE.xml);


        var newElement = new XElement("player", name,
            new XElement("age", age));

        doc.Element("players").Add(newElement);


        doc.Save(XMLFILE.xml);
```

If anyone could help, that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need the original instance of the form; a new instance will have its own variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way your code looks, both `name` and `age` are local variables which override the fields of your `Form1` class' instance.

Supposing that you do the save when you click a `btnSave` button on your form and without using an extra class, your code should look like this:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.name = characterTextBox.Text;
    this.age = characterAgeTextBox.Text;
    var file = "xmlfile.xml";
    var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
    var newElement = new XElement("player", name,
        new XElement("age", age));
    doc.Element("players").Add(newElement);
    doc.Save(file);
}
```

If you want to pass the saving to the other class, a simplified version of your code might look like this:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    name = characterTextBox.Text;
    age = characterAgeTextBox.Text;
    XmlUtility.Save(this);
}

class XmlUtility
{
    public static void Save(Form1 form)
    {
        string name = form.name;
        string age = form.age;
        var file = "xmlfile.xml";
        var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
        var newElement = new XElement("player", name,
            new XElement("age", age));
        doc.Element("players").Add(newElement);
        doc.Save(file);
    }
}
```

I just want to add that you might want to rethink a little bit the design of your application, maybe creating a `Character` class in order to hold / pass between classes the `Name`, `Age` and other properties.